# Laravel homestead: "No input file specified"

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

This is the output I get when entering my local site.

I'm using Windows and running Homestead with Vagrant on it. This is my homestead.yaml file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: D:/web/laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: laravel.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/public

databases:
    - laravel

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

As you see, I opted for a global homestead installation, in my user folder, mapping Laravel to a path in a secondary drive.

None of these solutions I found worked for me:

```
vagrant up --provision
vagrant provision
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: When you spin up the machine, can you log in there with `vagrant ssh`?

Comment: @Tpojka yes, I can do it. I have even noticed there's nothing within  /home/vagrant/code . Shouldn't be the Laravel app living there?

Comment: It certainly should. Try with command `vagrant reload --provision` from host system.

Comment: I tried it. It didn't work either.

Comment: When you start homestead machine with `homestead up` do you see `homestead-7: /home/vagrant/code => D:/web/laravel` or something similar in console output?

Comment: homestead up didn't work. I use vagrant up instead.

Comment: With vagrant up, I can see this: homestead-7: /vagrant => C:/Users/[my user]/Homestead which is not what I expected. I installed Homestead globally, but I mapped Homestead.yaml to a project in D:/web/laravel

Comment: Ok, to have `homestead` command available you have to make an alias. Check in docs how to do that yourself since I am using macOS. But it is not main issue here. Is spelling of directories and capital letters correct in `Homestead.yaml` - is `D:/web/laravel` correct use of upper and lower cases?

Comment: @Tpojka I'm using lowercase both in file system and Homestead.yaml

Comment: Hm, can't tell much. I tried to search/google for something like "vagrant windows shared folder doesn't show" but offered results are not identical although similar. Is destroying and installing again an option for you? Have you tried it already, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

My global Homestead installation did not work, but my per project installations are OK.

Per project set up is preferred; we are able to tweak each project independently if and when we need to.

I lost two weeks due to 'no iput file specified' (at global installation). Yet the per project process is easy.

The following video more than helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rs2Hzx4qBm8

Further let me use terms "host" (the machine) and "guest" (Homestead virtual machine, VM).

*This sure works as described with versions:*
Ubuntu 18.04, Virtualbox 5.2.18, Vagrant 2.1.5, Composer 1.7.2 - host.
Laravel Homestead 7.17.0, Laravel Installer 2.0.1 (Laravel 5.7) - guest.

1. Have Vagrant, Virtual Box (you can install the two per https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead), as well as Composer installed on the host,
2. `cd` where you wish to keep Laravel sites, then `mkdir LaravelSites`, `cd LaravelSites` and then
   `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel petrTest` (it takes time), to create the project (and add plenty packages), and then `cd petrTest` and `ls` to review it; I guess in this step I remember adding mbstring and perhaps one or two more packages per requests on terminal by hand (sudo apt install thePackage) for my first homestead project into my host,
3. `composer require laravel/homestead --dev`, to add homestead and yaml packages to the project,
4. `vendor/bin/homestead`, to run Homestead, so to install it into your project run `vendor/bin/homestead make`, and view your project (note you have just added Vagrantfile and mainly Homestead.yaml),
5. `nano Homestead.yaml`, review, and exit keeping it intact for your first project,
6. `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "madeUp@email.com"`, Enter, file (keep_suggested_file): Enter, Overwrite the current file?: y, passphrase: Enter, passphrase again: Enter,
7. `vagrant up` (it takes time and computing resources), then `vagrant ssh` to switch to your guest (VM), `cd code`, then `ls`; and in `/home/vagrant/code` of your guest you can see those same files that are in `/home/petr/LaravelSites/petrTest` of your host (the two directories are synced),
8. `logout` to leave the guest for the host, `sudo nano /etc/hosts`, then append `192.168.10.10  homestead.test` to the bottom and make sure to `Write Out` the changes. Then in the browser: `homestead.test`, Enter. You should see the Laravel web.

*Alternatively you can follow the nice and easy video, too.*